# Java TCP Clients/Servers and loop issues

Tags: java, loops, client, boolean

This is my first time making a **TCP Client/Server program**.  I am supposed to make a simple Java Client and Server program that asks the Client-side for a user-name and password.  From there the server checks its user database (which I attempted to create using a mulch-dimensional array) to see if there is a match and return to the Client a message saying "Hello " (username) and then tell the user all the other registered users on the server.

My **specific problem** however, is that whenever I run the two, when I arrive at the part were the Server is supposed to go through the loop, all that is displayed is *"Other users registered on the server currently include: MATTCARLJOHN Other users registered on the server currently include: MATTCARLJOHN Other users registered on the server currently include: MATTCARLJOHN"*.

It would seem that my server is completely ignoring my for loop and if statement that is supposed to check for authentication and skipping straight to that loop regardless on what I type in for my username and password on the client side.

**Here are the two programs:
The Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient2
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
         String userName;
         String passWord;
         String loginInfo;
         String loginInfo2;

         BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
         DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
         BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

         System.out.println("Username: ");
         userName = inFromUser.readLine();
         outToServer.writeBytes(userName + '\n');

         System.out.println("Password: ");
         passWord = inFromUser.readLine();
         outToServer.writeBytes(passWord + '\n');

         loginInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
         System.out.println(loginInfo);



         clientSocket.close();
     }
}
```

**and the Server**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer2
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        String[][] Login = {{"MATT","UNCP"},{"JOHN","UNCP"},{"CARL","UNCP"}};
        String username;
        String username1;
        String password;
        String password1;
        while(true)
        {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            username = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Username received: " + username);
            password = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Password received: " + password);
            username1=username.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            password1=password.toUpperCase() + '\n';

            for(int i = 0; i<Login.length; i++){
                if(Login[i][0].equals(username1) && Login[i][1].equals(password1)){
                    outToClient.writeBytes("Hello " + username1);
                    outToClient.writeBytes("Other users registered on the server currently include: ");
                    for(int k = 0; k<Login.length; k++){
                        outToClient.writeBytes(Login[k][0]);}
                else
                    outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid Username and/or password.");
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Any help would highly be appreciated, this is my first time posting on the site and I am very new to networking and Java in general so please forgive me if my questions seem confusing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending newlines to `username1` and `password1`. These newlines are not present in the hardcoded login credentials (`"MATT","UNCP"`), so the comparison...

```
if(Login[i][0].equals(username1) && Login[i][1].equals(password1)){
```

never succeeds.

Just omit the newlines from `username1` and `password1` (at least until after the `if`).

Oh and don't forget the newlines for all your messages, f.e.:

```
outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid Username and/or password.\n");
//                                                       /
//                                                 added the \n
```

Answer (score 0):

The code actually seems to work for me when I run it.  On the client is see:

```
$ java TCPClient -classpath .
Username:
blah
Password:
blah
```

On the server I see:

```
$ java TCPServer -classpath .
Username received: blah
Password received: blah
```

Comment: Yah, that is all that works for me as well, it is the large for-loop below it though that is my main problem however, and getting it to recognize a successful user log-in.